# Replacing in files with sed using regex

Tags: sed, regular-expression

i want to replace a string in many files like "Total:*points" using sed. I simply don't know how to use sed with regex. Below is what i got. Thank you in advance!

```
find ./ -iname "skp-corr-*.txt" -exec sed -i "" "s/(Total: )(.*)(points)/Total: X \/ 31 points/g" {} \;
```

Example file before:
Total: 4 / 22 points

Example file after:
Total: x / 30 points

Comment: Show your desired input and output.  Be specific about what you are changing to what.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the expected output from your sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is already built to use regex.

```
find ./ -iname "skp-corr-*.txt" -exec sed -i "s@Total:.*points@Total: X / 30 points@g" {} \;
```

For OS X,

```
find ./ -iname "skp-corr-*.txt" -exec sed -i "" -e "s@Total:.*points@Total: X / 30 points@g" {} \;
```

Comment: thanks, but now it says
    invalid command code .

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456518/invalid-command-code-despite-escaping-periods-using-sed
I'll update my answer to match that if you are on OS X